# Solving an implicit quadratic system of 3 variables

Tags: python, numpy, system, implicit, quadratic

I am trying to solve a system of equations that has 3 variables and a variable number of equations.

Basically, the system is between 5 and 12 equations long, and regardless of how many equations there are, I am trying to solve for 3 variables.

It looks like this:

```
(x-A)**2 + (y-B)**2 + (z-C)**2 = (c(t-d))**2
```

I know A,B,C, and the whole right side.
A,B,C and the right side are all arrays of length n, where n varies randomly between 5 and 12. So then we have a system of equations that changes in size. 
I believe I need to use numpy's lstsq function and do something like:

```
data,data1 = getData()        # I will have to do this for 2 unique systems.
A   = data[:,0]
B   = data[:,1]
C   = data[:,2]
tid = data[:,3]
P = (x-A)**2 + (y-B)**2 + (z-C)**2              
b = tid
solved = lstsq(P,b)
print solved
```

This however doesn't work, as we know that x,y,z are implicit, and therefore need to be taken out of P in order for this to work. 
Help!

Comment: What does getData() return? A tuple of two arrays? Anyway, I think you need a system of (not less than) three equations, and they have to be **linearly independent** (it's important!), to find out the value of x,y,z. Because you'd extract each unknown value as *lvalue* and replace it in the other two, then repeat the process for the second so you'll have an equation with only one unknown value. Then you can solve it and replace the result and repeat the process for the other two. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is [scipy.optimize.minimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)() which works with arbitrary (nonlinear) equations.  numpy.linalg.lstsq() only solves a system of *linear* equations, and this problem is pretty definitely nonlinear (although there are techniques to linearize systems of equations, I think this is not what you want in this case).

It is likely that a system of >3 equations in 3 variables has no solution, so you have to define how to measure how good a given "solution" is even though it doesn't actually solve the system of equations.  How to pose this as a minimization problem depends on the physical or problem-domain interpretation what you are trying to actually do.  One possibility is, for the following equations (which are a slightly rearranged version of yours)

```
(x-A1)**2 + (y-B1)**2 + (z-C1)**2 - T1**2 = 0
(x-A2)**2 + (y-B2)**2 + (z-C2)**2 - T2**2 = 0
...
```

try to minimize the sum of the absolute values of all the left hand sides (which should be zero if the equation is solved exactly).  In other words, you want the x, y, z that produce the minimum of the following function

```
sum( abs( (x-A1)**2 + (y-B1)**2 + (z-C1)**2 - T1**2 ) + abs( (x-A2)**2 + (y-B2)**2 + (z-C2)**2 - T2**2 ) + ... )
```

Code example: v is ndarray of (3,) containing x, y, z; and A, B, C, tid are ndarrays of (N,) where N is the number of equations.

```
def F(v, A, B, C, tid):
    x = v[0]
    y = v[1]
    z = v[2]
    return numpy.sum( numpy.abs( (x-A)**2 + (y-B)**2 + (z-C)**2 - tid ) )

v_initial = numpy.array([x0, y0, z0]) # starting guesses
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(F, v_initial, args=(A, B, C, tid))
v = result.x
x, y, z = v.tolist() # the best solution found
```

This should be close to working but I haven't tested it.  You may need some extra arguments to minimize(), for example method, tol, ...

Comment: @KevinSchaffer: Please have a look and let me know if this works for you.